# Modify PayPal Express Checkout custom parameter after payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout, for recurring payments without any trial.

For the first payment, I'm using `DoExpressCheckoutPayment API Operation (NVP)`, and store reference value in custom parameter.

Before making payment, I don't have a customer ID, as it is generated after payment is made, so I'm using the reference value in custom parameter for validating payments and register customer later

Is there a way to modify the custom parameter later, which was set in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`?
I want to add the customer id to it, to ease the future IPN, as reference ID might not be available later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that cannot be modified later.  What I would recommend is to create the customer record in your system prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  You could create it with a pending status or something like that, and then update the status once the payment is completed.  This way you'll have the ID you need and can attach it to the payment.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, seems the only way to go with :)